# node app to prompt user to enter an input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and was trying to implement a simple app in which the user should be prompted to enter the direction in which they want to move but it does not work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
///////////////////////////////////////////
const handleInput = (userInput) => {
  const str = userInput.toString().trim();
  let output;
  if (process.argv[2] === 'up') {
    output = ///move up
  } 
  if (process.argv[2] === 'right') {
    output = ///move to the right
  } 
  if (process.argv[2] === 'left') {
    output = ///move to the left
  } 
  
  process.stdout.write(output + '\n');
  process.exit();
}

// Run the program.
process.stdout.write('Which direction do you want to move ?\n> ');
process.stdin.on('data', handleInput);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `readline.Interface.question` instead of `process.stdin.on`.

Try the following code (and change it for your needs):

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Which direction do you wanna move ? ", (userInput) => {
    const str = userInput.toString().trim();
    let output;
    if (str === 'up') {
      output = "move up";
    } 
    if (str === 'right') {
      output = "move to the right";
    } 
    if (str === 'left') {
      output = "move to the left";
    } 
    
    console.log(output + "\n");
    rl.close();
});

rl.on("close", () => {
    console.log("\nBYE BYE !!!");
    process.exit(0);
});
```

I hope this helps.